# Python script to query REST API and write to database

Tags: python, beginner, json, rest, odbc

I wrote the following sample script for learning purposes:

```
import requests
import json
import pyodbc
import os
import sys

source_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'

query_posts_response = requests.get(source_url)

if (query_posts_response.status_code == 200):
    posts = json.loads(query_posts_response.content.decode('utf-8'))

db_connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
    "Server=(local);"
    "Database=sandbox;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

sys_devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys_stdout_original = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = sys_devnull

db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()

for post in posts:
    db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Posts(id, title) VALUES (?, ?)", post['id'], post['title'])

db_connection.commit()
db_connection.close()

sys.stdout = sys_stdout_original
```

I'm grabbing content from a REST API, and I'm inserting it into a relational table.

I write scripts in other languages, but this is my first Python script. I don't know what I don't know. I'm looking for a critique. I realize I was lazy on the database call and didn't create an exception handler. That said, is this the generally accepted way to interface with a REST endpoint and interact with a database?

Concerning output of `db_cursor.execute()`, see the following:

[image]

Comment: Why do you redefine `sys.stdout` during the database operations?

Comment: I was running this through the REPL while I was writing it. The `execute()` call generated all this jibber jabber so I piped it to /dev/null. Probably doesn't make sense in a script?

Comment: `execute()` should be silent. It doesn't ever make sense to squelch stdout.

Comment: Noted feedback on not squelching stdout as a best practice; thank you. Sadly, `execute()` is not silent - see revised post.

Comment: You only see those results because you are running the code in a REPL. That's the point of the "P" in "[REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop)". If you don't want to see the results, don't run the code in a REPL.

Comment: To your point about the REPL, I think I mentioned that in my first response, but thank you for further clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. A linter (or two) such as pycodestyle or flake8 will help you write more idiomatic Python. For example, brackets are not required around an `if` statement.
2. You can use `query_posts_response.json()` to easily get JSON response content.
3. I can't see a reason why this script should do anything with the input and output streams.
4. `db_connection.close()` should be in a `finally` block. The `try` block should start with creating the connection.
5. If you ever intend to reuse the code it should be wrapped inside at least a `main` function (which orchestrates argument parsing, handling exceptions which should lead to non-zero return codes, and the like) and a separate function to do the work.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of feedback I was looking for.